# Xcode Simulator not displaying app name on launch

Tags: ios, xcode

Following [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH5-SW1) for the 5th time to the letter,

1. Create Singe View Application
2. Run Simulator

I see a blank Simulator with the carrier time and battery bar, but **no app name and no credits** like there should be according to the following picture from the docs :

Apple says:

```
[Before the app finishes launching, you’ll briefly see a launch screen with your app’s name, FoodTracker.][1]
```

Running Xcode-beta and Swift 2.2

Comment: check your LaunchScreen.xib

Comment: 1. Add a link to the documentation you are following. 2. There are no guarantees about how *briefly* the launch screen will be visible. 3. As already explained by @EICaptain , LaunchScreen.xib is shown during that brief time

Comment: aegh. above screenshot shows the app name

Answer (score 1):

Apple clearly states in [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html) that

> A launch file or image provides
>
> - simple placeholder that iOS displays when your app starts up
> - is quickly replaced by the first screen of your app

also,

> the launch image isn’t an opportunity to provide:
>
> - An “app entry experience,” such as a splash screen
> - An About window
> - Branding elements, unless they are a static part of your app’s first
>     screen

So, its supposed to be visible while your app loads. If your app loads fast enough, the launch screen might not be visible long enough for you to notice.

Comment: Considering that the OP has done nothing but create a single-view app from the template, he/she likely has about the fastest-loading app one can create.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the only constructive response. @lukya

Answer (score 0):

I had the some problem but i fortuitous found a quiet simple solution using the Launch Screen.storyboard created automatic with the app.

Open the App-Settings and there App Icons and Launch Images

[image]

Select **Launch Screen.storyboard** in the DropDown-List, even when u think, this is already selected. The display of the screen won´t change after selecting. But when restart the project, the Launch Screen was showed!

BTW to test this tidy, u can set a breakpont in the last line of
*func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)*